# Ruby Binary Search not noticing values already in array some of the time

Tags: ruby, binary-search

I'm adding items to an array. To add them, I have my application binary search my current array, if it's there - it doesn't add the item. If the item isn't there, it gets added:

```
while (line = fileObj.gets)

  itemD = line.split(" ")
  number = itemD.at(0)
  name = itemD.at(1)

  if (search(items, number) == -1)
    # Doesn't add if item already exists
    puts "Already have: #{number} - #{name}"
  else
    # Adds a new item to the list
    items << Item.new(number, name)
  end
end
```

Above, my loop reads input from a file, takes the number and name. Then searches for the number. The above code works perfectly fine, so it's the code below (The binary search) that isn't working correctly:

```
def search(array, key)
  min = 0
  max = array.length-1
  mid = 0

  while(min <= max)
    mid = lo + ((min - max)/2)

    if array[mid].number == key
      return -1
    elsif array[mid].number < key
      min = mid + 1
    else
      max = mid - 1
    end
  end

  puts "#{key} not found in array"
end
```

I noticed the issue when using my basic test case:

```
58        Item 1
17        Item 2
58        Item 3
76        Item 4
06        Item 5
08        Item 6
17        Item 7
21        Item 8
76        Item 4
76        Item 4
00        Item 9
49        Item 10
40        Item 11
79        Item 12
31        Item 13
```

Despite the different name, it doesn't add item 3 (which is good, because the number already exists). Then it gets to the second item 4. It adds that one, but then gets to the THIRD item 4, and notices it's in the array and doesn't add it. My output is as follow (to help trace the issue):

```
58 not found in array
17 not found in array
Already have: 58 - Item 3
76 nfia
06 nfia
08 nfia
17 nfia
21 nfia
76 nfia (WRONG)
Already have: 76 - Item 4 (CORRECT)
00 nfia
49 nfia
40 nfia
79 nfia
31 nfia
```

Next I made a test case with only 1 item multiple times:

```
58        Item 1
58        Item 1
58        Item 1
58        Item 1
58        Item 1
```

It correctly adds the first, and notices the next 4 (and properly doesn't add them). So clearly it has more to do if the number comes up later in the list as opposed to right after it was just added. So next I tested:

```
58        Item 1
08        Item 6
58        Item 1
08        Item 6
58        Item 1
08        Item 6
58        Item 1
08        Item 6
58        Item 1
08        Item 6
```

This shows what I'm referring to with the output, but an interesting iteration of it:

```
58 nfia
08 nfia
Already have 58
08 nfia (WRONG)
58 nfia (WRONG)
already have
already have
already have
already have
already have
```

Can someone help me with why it notices the element in my array SOME of the time, but not EVERY time when it should. Thanks for the assistance, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Other than mentioning that Ruby provides the method [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) to perform binary searches, I will let others address the problem with your binary search method. I would like to suggest a more Ruby-like way to perform the task.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def process_file(fname)
  s = Set.new
  items = []
  File.foreach(fname) do |line|
    pair = line.split
    if s.add?(pair)
      items << Item.new(*pair)
    else
      puts "Already have: %s - %s" % pair
    end
  end
  items
end
```

**Example**

Let's create a test file.

```
str =<<_
Humpty Dumpty
sat on
a wall.
Humpty Dumpty
had a
great fall.
_

FName = "test"

File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 61
```

Let's check it.

```
puts File.read(FName)
Humpty Dumpty
sat on
a wall.
Humpty Dumpty
had a
great fall.
```

We need a class `Item`.

```
class Item
  def initialize(*pair)
    @pair = pair
  end
end
```

We're ready to go.

```
process_file(FName)
  Already have: Humpty - Dumpty
  #=> [#<Item:0x007f978404e2f0 @pair=["Humpty", "Dumpty"]>,
  #    #<Item:0x007f978404c810 @pair=["sat", "on"]>,
  #    #<Item:0x007f9784046370 @pair=["a", "wall."]>,
  #    #<Item:0x007f978403ced8 @pair=["had", "a"]>,
  #    #<Item:0x007f9784037e88 @pair=["great", "fall."]>]
```

See [Set::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new), [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach), [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split) and [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F). `IO` methods (such as `foreach`) are commonly invoked on the class `File`, which is a subclass of `IO`.

Comment: I was attempting to not do it the Ruby way. That being said, in other parts of my code not shown I also have my own sort method. So my goal was not to use Ruby's methods.

Answer (score 0):

> The above code works perfectly fine, so it's the code below (The binary search) that isn't working correctly

This statement is wrong: the above code does *not* "work perfectly fine". In particular, binary search requires the sequence to be sorted, so you need to either sort it before calling `search` or make sure to insert the new items at the correct place, so that the array is always sorted. However, you simply stick the item to the end of the array regardless of its `number`, and you never sort the array.

There is also a second bug in that the object referenced by your `number` is actually a `String` and not a number. That might just be bad naming of the variable, but from the rest of the code, it looks like it is actually intended to be a number. In particular, I am not sure that you actually intend `11` to be less than `2`, which is the case for strings.

There is also at least one bug in your `search` method: `lo` isn't defined anywhere.

Assuming you mean `min` instead, the formula is still wrong, it should be `min + ((max - min) / 2)`, not the other way round. But, actually, the whole gymnastics aren't necessary. This is only needed in languages where arithmetic is broken. Ruby is perfectly capable of adding two integers together without errors, so you can just do `(min + max) / 2`.

Another problem is that the return value of your `search` method doesn't really make sense. For one, the return value is useless for actually getting the item. I would expect a `search` method to either return me the item or (in the case of an indexable sequence like an array) alternatively the index of the item. Your `search` method returns `-1` if the item exists and `nil` if it doesn't. So, in other words, it only tells you whether the item exists or not. That's not terribly useful: imagine if you typed your search query into Google and it would just return "Yep, what you are searching for exists. But I'm not telling you where!" Or, you ask someone to help you search for your contact lens which you accidentally dropped, and they tell you "Found it!" and then just walk away.

There are generally two forms of binary search: one returns the index of the element if it exists, and something else (e.g. `-1` or `nil` or `NULL` or some other special designated value) otherwise to tell you that the item doesn't exist. The other form always returns the index of where the item would belong in the sequence if it were there. Since binary search requires the array to be sorted, but sorting the array doesn't make sense (you probably use binary search because it only requires O(log n) comparisons as opposed to O(n) for a linear search, but sorting would take O(n * log n) comparisons (or O(n) for a non-comparison based sort, since your keys are numbers), so would actually be slower overall than a simple linear search), you will instead have to insert the items at the correct place in the sequence which means you need a form of binary search which tells you the index the item belongs, even if it isn't there (*especially* if it isn't there, so you can insert it at the right place).

Unfortunately, fixing all those bugs and design errors would go beyond the scope of a simple Stack Overflow answer.

I want to present an alternative instead: one of the most important steps in designing a program is to decide which data structures to use. In this case, you want to have no duplicates in your array, which seems to indicate that you actually don't want an array at all, but rather a set. Maybe, you want a sorted set, but from your description, and your code, it doesn't actually look like you need that property.

So, I would suggest something like this:

```
class Item < Struct.new(:number, :name)
  def eql?(other)
    number.eql?(other.number)
  end

  def hash
    number.hash
  end

  # the following are only needed for a sorted set

  def <=>(other)
    number <=> other.number
  end

  include Comparable
end

require 'set'

items = File.foreach('filename.txt').
  map {|line| number, name = line.chomp.split(nil, 2); Item.new(number.to_i, name) }.
  to_set
#=> #<Set: {#<struct Item number=58, name="Item 1">,
            #<struct Item number=17, name="Item 2">,
            #<struct Item number=76, name="Item 4">,
            #<struct Item number=6,  name="Item 5">,
            #<struct Item number=8,  name="Item 6">,
            #<struct Item number=21, name="Item 8">,
            #<struct Item number=0,  name="Item 9">,
            #<struct Item number=49, name="Item 10">,
            #<struct Item number=40, name="Item 11">,
            #<struct Item number=79, name="Item 12">,
            #<struct Item number=31, name="Item 13">}>

# if you want a sorted set instead:

items = SortedSet.new(File.foreach(filename.txt)) {|line| 
  number, name = line.chomp.split(nil, 2); Item.new(number.to_i, name)
}
#=> #<SortedSet: {#<struct Item number=0,  name="Item 9">,
                  #<struct Item number=6,  name="Item 5">,
                  #<struct Item number=8,  name="Item 6">,
                  #<struct Item number=17, name="Item 2">,
                  #<struct Item number=21, name="Item 8">,
                  #<struct Item number=31, name="Item 13">,
                  #<struct Item number=40, name="Item 11">,
                  #<struct Item number=49, name="Item 10">,
                  #<struct Item number=58, name="Item 1">,
                  #<struct Item number=76, name="Item 4">,
                  #<struct Item number=79, name="Item 12">}>
```